# Loop insert problem, reload page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Im trying to achieve an insert statment and return using my function in the pageload. Not sure how I can insert at the same time draw what i inserted into mysql back out again all in one go?

Code:

```
public partial class UserProfileWall : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=user_name; Password=password_here;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))

            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    divHtml.Append("<div id=test>");
                    divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
                    divHtml.Append("</div>");
                }
                test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=user_name; Password=password_here;");
        cn.Open();

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //    {
    //        using (OdbcCommand md = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + theUserId + "", cn))

    //        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    //        {
    //            var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //            while (reader.Read())
    //            {
    //                divHtml.Append("<div id=test>");
    //                divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
    //                divHtml.Append("</div>");
    //            }
    //            test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
}
```

I did try the commented out line but I got multiple inserts and nothing reloaded on the page. Is there a simple way after I insert to get the pageload function?

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly the issue is - what insert? Into the DB? On the page? Where is the problem? Initial load? Postbacks?

Comment: scroll down on the code the insert is in the button click event, this takes something the user types and inserts in mysql then I need to reload the page somehow be4 loosing the users text when I insert and posting back the info via my page load function i.e the select loop

Comment: On another note you should move your connection string into your web.config or at the very least into a static variable somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, move the code that populate the element with the wall posts to separate function:

```
private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=user_name; Password=password_here;"))
        {
        cn.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + userId) + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
        {
            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    divHtml.Append("<div id=test>");
                    divHtml.Append(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0)));
                    divHtml.Append("</div>");
                }
                test1.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now call this in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
}
```

And finally call it after inserting the new value:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=user_name; Password=password_here;"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
}
```

Your commented code didn't work because you executed the `INSERT INTO` command again instead the SELECT command.

Anyway, you really better learn about SQL Injection and change your code to use Parameters instead of directly adding the user ID to the SQL string.

Comment: @spender thanks, it's quite glaring to my eyes. Used to see it all around ever since classic ASP. :/

Comment: shadow could you look at this post maybe you could help me out similar to this problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419192/multiple-records-displayed-due-to-code